# how to update and insert millions of record in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, cpu-usage

i have developing enterprise level application with more than 60 threads for update and inserting the data from 10 sql server to one Enterprise sql server using vb.net desktop application.

my issue is while updating  more than 10 million data in each server than my cpu uses and memory uses almost 100%

system configuration: 32GB RAM, Server OS 2008, SQL server 2008

Comment: How are you pushing this data to SQL Server?  Via draconian insert scripts from a computer other than the server itself?  Look into use bulk insert for faster results.

Comment: Consider explaining the architecture of you application and structure of the data in a bit more detail? For example, where is the application running? Is the application pushing data from the source server to the Enterprise or pulling from Enterprise? What is the nature of the data itself? Is it a simple table on the destination with small rows or a table with large rows and numerous indexes/constraints etc?

Comment: i am pushing data from various plant server using link server

Answer (score 0):

If you don't enforce constraints on the target table like foreign keys, etc and disable all indices during this migration, it will be faster

Comment: i have one table with 50 column(approx) in this table i have two indexing, if i am disable updation operation then my insert operation(using bulk) which is working very fast, but when i start updating with insert then it will slow